# java.lang.Object.equals and java.lang.Object.hashCode have trouble with jruby object after serialization

Tags: jruby, equals, hashcode

I have some trouble using jruby objects into java

java side

```java
package com.pp;

public interface ZeroI {

    boolean equals(Object o);    
    int hashCode();    
    int hash();
}


package com.pp;

public class Tester {

    public Object[] compare(ZeroI one, ZeroI two) {
        return new Object[] {one.hashCode(), two.hashCode(), one.equals(two), one == two};
    }
}
```

jruby side

```rb
include Java

import com.pp.Tester
import com.pp.ZeroI

module MMM

    module Zero

        def hash= value
            @hash = value
        end

        def hash
            @hash
        end

        def hashCode
            @hash
        end

        def equals other
            false
        end

        def == other
            true
        end

    end

    class OneClass
        include ZeroI
        include Zero
    end

    class TwoClass
        include ZeroI
        include Zero
    end

    def self.create clazz
        begin
            dump = IO.readlines("C:/#{clazz.to_s.rpartition('::')[2]}.txt", '').to_s
            instance = Marshal.load dump
        rescue => err
            puts err.message
            instance = clazz.new
            dump = Marshal.dump instance
            File.open("C:/#{clazz.to_s.rpartition('::')[2]}.txt", 'w') { |f| f.write dump }
        end
        instance
    end

    tester = Tester.new
    one = create OneClass
    two = create TwoClass

    puts one
    puts two

    one.hash = 22
    two.hash = 22

    puts one.hashCode
    puts two.hashCode
    puts one.equals two
    puts one == two

    tester.compare(one, two).each { |value| puts value }
end
```

## First pass result:

```
No such file or directory - C:/OneClass.txt

No such file or directory - C:/TwoClass.txt
#<MMM::OneClass:0x1971eb3>
#<MMM::TwoClass:0x1408a75>
22    
22    
false    
true    
22    
22    
true
false
```

true # it's OK because JAVA.equals works with JRUBY.==

false # it's OK because org.pp.ZeroI can't declare == method and JAVA.== is used

## Second pass result (with deserialized objects)

```
#<MMM::OneClass:0xd510e8>
#<MMM::TwoClass:0x490342>
22    
22    
false    
true    
13046738 # but what is it?    
31877484 # but what is it?    
false # but what is it?    
false
```

Can anybody explain it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know all the details about why this happens like it happens but I have a solution/workaround for you. (I've seen similar behaviour when passing objects that are created on the ruby side to the Java side.)

As far as I can tell JRuby needs to have already "seen" an instance of the class it is trying to unmarshal before it can get the Java-inheritance side of things right. It's almost as if creating an object within JRuby has an undocumented side-effect that registers the required inheritance hierarchy. If that isn't well worded it's because I don't understand it myself!

So the workaround is to simply create an instance of `OneClass` and `TwoClass` before doing the unmarshal. If I change the `self.create` method to the following:

```rb
def self.create clazz
    begin
        clazz.new # <<< just create an instance and throw it away!
        dump = IO.readlines("C:/#{clazz.to_s.rpartition('::')[2]}.txt", '').to_s
        instance = Marshal.load dump
    rescue => err
        puts err.message
        instance = clazz.new
        dump = Marshal.dump instance
        File.open("C:/#{clazz.to_s.rpartition('::')[2]}.txt", 'w') { |f| f.write dump }
    end
    instance
end
```

Then the output of the two passes are as follows:

### First pass

```
No such file or directory - C:/OneClass.txt
No such file or directory - C:/TwoClass.txt
#<MMM::OneClass:0x4de6f0ef>
#<MMM::TwoClass:0x4526ba64>
22
22
false
true
22
22
true
false
```

### Second pass

```
#<MMM::OneClass:0x4858cca9>
#<MMM::TwoClass:0x3de4905a>
22
22
false
true
22
22
true
false
```

According to [this bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5317) this is scheduled to be fixed in JRuby 1.7. It's worth noting that while the comments in the report say that the workaround is to call a method, passing an object instance in, it seems to be that the prior creation of the object is enough.

Comment: >As far as I can tell JRuby needs to have already "seen" an instance >of the class it is trying to unmarshal before it can get the Java->inheritance side of things right.

Comment: > As far as I can tell JRuby needs to have already "seen" an instance of the class it is trying to unmarshal before it can get the Java-inheritance side of things right.

Thanks

I already use this technique to ensure the correct operation of the keyword "instanceof" on the side of Java.
But it is not very convenient, because the system has to deal with the types of objects that are created by users, ie arbitrary. So it's not a systemic solution, but I have not another until there.